# random number generator not displaying numbers properly when asigning specific min and max

Tags: javascript, html

When assigning the min to 1 and max to 1000 its outputting correct random numbers, but when assigning min to 100 and lets say max to 110 its still outputting random numbers like 1,45,27,83,14,52,5... instead of the range from 100-110

```js
 function randomNumber(min,max){
            min= document.getElementById("minnumber").value;
            max= document.getElementById("maxnumber").value;
            if(max < min){
                alert("Min is greater than max!")
            } else {
                result=(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min))
            }
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML=result
        }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Number Generator</h1>
            <p>Select between what range you want to randomize a number</p>
            
                <label for="minnumber">min number</label>
                <input type="text" id="minnumber" placeholder="Enter min number">
                <label for="maxnumber">max number</label>
                <input type="text" id="maxnumber" placeholder="Enter max number" >
                <button id="btn" onclick="randomNumber()"> Generate number </button>
            <p id="number">Generated Number</p>   
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: why are you getting `(min,max)` as parameter? also, you should _declare_ your variable (e.g. `result`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `parseInt` function, to convert the value of inputs (which is a `string`) to a `number`. Also, since you are directly taking the value from `input`, there is no need of `min` and `max` parameters.
The program works fine then.

```js
function randomNumber() {
  let min = parseInt(document.getElementById("minnumber").value);
  let max = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxnumber").value);
  if (max < min) {
    alert("Min is greater than max!")
  } else {
    result = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min))
  }
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = result
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Number Generator</h1>
    <p>Select between what range you want to randomize a number</p>

    <label for="minnumber">min number</label>
    <input type="text" id="minnumber" placeholder="Enter min number">
    <label for="maxnumber">max number</label>
    <input type="text" id="maxnumber" placeholder="Enter max number">
    <button id="btn" onclick="randomNumber()"> Generate number </button>
    <p id="number">Generated Number</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need `(min, max)` parameters, since you are not passing any parameters, furthermore when you are getting value from input box you are receiving them as `string` which you need to convert to `integer`, so you would use the following:

```
min = parseInt(document.getElementById("minnumber").value);
max = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxnumber").value);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Still not displaying properly, try and input min=100 and max=120 and it will only display numbers from 0 to 20, try the code snippet

Comment: @gogimylo It works just fine, here's jsfiddle and you can try it there. https://jsfiddle.net/rvx71ymf/ Edit: I did miss out `parseInt()` on the second line in the code, I did fix it.

Comment: okay, it works now, something was also with my vscode-browser connection so I opened a new file and it works! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  function randomNumber(min,max){
            min= parseInt(document.getElementById("minnumber").value);
            max= parseInt(document.getElementById("maxnumber").value);
            if(max < min){
                alert("Min is greater than max!")
            } else {
                result=(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min))
            }
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML=result
        }
```